# Parse Article Content for Template Layout

Tags: articles, template-override, twitter-bootstrap-2

I want to create a layout (or override) that i can run a foreach loop on the div's of certain classes. Is there a method in joomla to help me? I have seen a little about php HTML DOM parser but I thought someone might know a simple way

I am thinking I have to parse the content into an array first then I can loop the layout.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if a client side solution would work for you, but this sounds like a job for jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.classname').each(index, function(){

    // preform task on each class instance

})
</script>
```

Comment: perhaps. I am actually trying to build a layout that makes it easy to put the content in bootstrap modals so that might be the way to go. I want to be able to allow the client to only insert this structure in the article.
`<div class="list1">
<dl></dl>
</div>
<div class="list2">
...`
or ids

Promise I will post my solution

Comment: As for wrapping the content php side stutteringp0et shared this in the forum. [link](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=620&t=794503&view=next#p3002833)

Comment: so far i am here
`$dom = new DOMDocument;
 $dom->loadHTML($this->item->introtext);
$main = $dom->find('div[id=main]',0); ?>`
but my HTML is crapped..

Comment: sorry I'm not familiar with parsing html using PHP. Maybe someone else could help there.

Comment: I did a preg_match_all. Thanks for you attention though. I posted what I did

Answer (score 1):

This wraps a bunch of lists in an article for modals

```
// find what I am looking for
if (preg_match_all("'<h4>(.*?)</h4>\n?<dl id=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</dl>' si", $this->item->introtext, $matches)) :

$lists = array();

// adjust array so I know what I am working with a better
for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]) ; $i++)
{
    // preg match all creates an array for each item wrapped in parens after full match
    $lists[$i] = new stdClass();
    $lists[$i]->name = $matches[1][$i];
    $lists[$i]->id = $matches[2][$i];
    $lists[$i]->data = $matches[3][$i];
} ?>

<div class="row-fluid">
<?php foreach($lists as $list) : ?>

    <a class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="#<?php echo $list->id; ?>" data-toggle="modal"><?php echo $list->name; ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
<?php foreach($lists as $list) : ?>

    <div id="<?php echo $list->id; ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">

        <div class="modal-header"><button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3><?php echo $this->item->category_title; ?> - <?php echo $list->name; ?></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <dl>
                <?php echo  $list->data; ?>
            </dl>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>

    </div>

<?php   endforeach; ?>

<?php   endif; // end here ?>
```